# Como adicionar apenas 1 vez o mesmo item no carrinho ? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, react

Como faria para adicionar apenas 1 vez o mesmo item no carrinho?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import * as S from './styles'

//Components
import ImgCar from '../src/components/imgs/car.svg';

class Car extends Component {

  state = {
    carAdd: [],
    car: [
      {
        id: 0,
        name: "Jetta",
        assembler: "Volkswagen",
        price: 144000,
        type: "Sedan",
        btnDisabled: false
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Polo",
        assembler: "Volkswagen",
        price: 70000,
        type: "Hatch",
        btnDisabled: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "T-Cross",
        assembler: "Volkswagen",
        price: 123000,
        type: "SUV",
        btnDisabled: false
      }
     
    ]
  }

  funcBtnAdd = (event) => {
    const check = this.state.car.filter(item => item.id == event.id);
    event.btnDisabled = true;
    console.log(check)
    this.setState({
      carAdd: this.state.carAdd.concat(check)
    })
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

Se check for o carro a ser adicionado, faria o seguinte:

```
  funcBtnAdd = (event) => {
    const check = this.state.car.filter(item => item.id == event.id);
    event.btnDisabled = true;

    const isCarAlreadyAdded = this.carAdd.some(car => car.id === check.id);
    
    if (!isCarAlreadyAdded) {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        carAdd: [...prevState, check]
      }))
    }
  }
```

Explicação: A função some retorna true se a condição passada for verdadeira.
Então, ela verfica se no array de carros já adicionados (carAdd) já existe o novo carro a ser inserido. Caso sim, o valor da variável isCarAlreadyAdded será true, e o estado não será atualizado.

Comment: Muito obrigado, entendi a lógica. Vou testar aqui e já já passo se deu bug ou se ta ok. grato